# How may I create notation for minimisation or maximisation over parameters?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to create notation for minimisation or maximisation over parameters such as the notation shown here:

[image]

I have a solution which is very inelegant. What do you think would be the neatest approach to creating this notation in LaTeX?

Comment: How about showing this "very inelegant" solution?

Comment: The rationale for not showing my solution is to avoid creating bias in the possible answers. My approach involved the use of underset and arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`amsmath` has a `\substack` for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\min_
{\left\{\substack{
p^{\mathrm{miss}},E^{\mathrm{miss}}\\
(p^{\mathrm{miss}})^2=0}
\right\}}
[(p^l + p^{\mathrm{miss}})^2]
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much for your assistance.